# Zend Framework 2: Bcrypt endless hashing

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, bcrypt

I have problem with Bcrypt which I'm using to secure password after registration.
When I press submit button the page can't stop executing script. Without Bcrypt everything works fine.
Here is part of my script:

```
public function saveUser(RegisterUser $user)
{
    $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
    $bcrypt->setCost(28);
    $pass = $bcrypt->create($user->password);


    $data = array(
        'login' => $user->login,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => $pass,
    );


     $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
}
```

It doesn't matter if I set setCost() to 14 or 28 the problem is same.
I'm using Windows 7 and xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cost factor is ways too high, a usual value is about 10. Keep in mind that this cost factor is logarithmic, that means increasing the factor by 1 doubles the necessery calculation time.

Comment: Script works if I set cost value to 10, but is it secure value?

Comment: @user1409508 - It is a reasonable value (today in 2013), but actually we should ask the other way round: how much time are you willing to spend? The best you can do is, to measure the time your server needs for hashing, then tune the cost-factor, so it will not slow down your system. You can begin with 10 and increase the cost-factor later, when you see that your server is idle all the time.